# 5x5 raster filter in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, dem, filter

Normally, I use the 3x3 lowpass filter if I need to filter a DEM. However in one case, for better results in curvature calculations, I would like to do 5x5 filtering. How is this possible in ArcGIS 10.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Focal statistics tool and choose your 5x5 there or create your own kernel for it. Low-Pass is quite easy as it is just the mean which can be chosen for this tool as well.